# JPA Modularization and Entities Relationship

Tags: java, jpa, modularity

I am trying to split a monolitic ERP into modules (sales, inventory, finance...) so they can be sold as a unit or in a combination of any of them. 
As I'm using JPA the problem comes when dealing with Foreign Keys since they are represented as collections.
If each module, in a separated jar file, has its own set of entities, how do they relate between each other? Should I get rid of FK's? If so what's the point in continue working with JPA?

Comment: Can you give an example? To me, if it has a FK relationship, you can't split the two entities apart, anyway. The way I deal with that is that I ship the (complete) model and add controller/view as needed.

Comment: For what environments do you sell the packages? Is that Java EE?

Comment: I'd try not split up the entities but keep them as part of one shared module. Apparently it is also going to stay one database.

Comment: Thank you for answering @mabi. What I'm trying to do by modularizing my app is to deliver a new release only to the customers that really need the new added/modified functionality.

Comment: @AndreiI The env is J2SE using JWS on Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have three options, none being bullet proof:

1. Share somehow the common entities. For example it is pretty clear that the Customer entity is used in every package. Of course the best way is to package all entities in an entity jar and provide it when selling other packages. After all you sell the business logic, not the entity mapping.
2. Make some ugly abstractions, getting rid of the FKs. In this way you will have to change the code. E.g instead of relating entities from other modules, you could use an embedded (relatedEntityClass, relatedEntityId). With this solution you will have problems when you'll need to join/ eager load the other entity, for example.
3. Sell the entire code and use some passwords/online activation for enabling modules.

Comment: Is it possible to make such abstractions in JPA?

Comment: What I mean is not a standard abstraction, but rather an workaround. See my updated answer (for the third option).

Comment: Option 3 is the way we've been working so far. What I'm trying to do is not deliver releases to customers that do not use any functionality involved in that specific release